# Magento different price range for each currency

Tags: magento

I have two currencies, USD and the Iranial rial.

When I set the currency range for USD price range in RIAL it is not fine.

**How can I change the price range for each currency?**

For example in `$1-$69` for dollar and `IRR3-IRR200,000`  for the rial?

Comment: I have the same question...I need to change price range between store/category/currency but I found nothing about currency :(